# Download/Publish an Asset as a single video file in Azure Media Services V3

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-media-services, azureportal

We're using Azure Media Services v3 for streaming and broadcasting videos and storing them for VoD.
The assets that we get in the end are entirely playable, however, we'd like to add a feature of downloading the Asset as a single file (mp4 preferably).

The main problem is that the Asset that Azure created, is consisted of a bunch of folders (for each quality):

[image]

and each of those folders contains a huge amount of chunks:

[image]

So, there's no single file to download.

Is there a way to download an asset as a single video file (or get a download link)?
If yes, any sample of that is welcome (as I couldn't find any after hours of googling).

P.S. I saw the solution "[How to: Deliver an asset by download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-asset-download)" but that's about the older Azure Media Services V2, not V3.
P.P.S. The [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/job-download-results-how-to) documentation with AMS V3 doesn't help either, as it blindly downloads the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the archive of a live event, which is always stored in fragmented Mp4 format.

To get a downloadable standard MP4 from the archive you would have to create a Transform that either re encodes the content or use one of the Copy Codec preset examples to copy the source to an MP4 output quickly without re encoding.  There are several copy codec examples in the Typescript/Node.js samples repo on GitHub.